# dot net core call appsettings from seperate class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I was looking at dotnet core the other day and I was testing out how to call `appsettings.json` to the general logic.

This works as expected but it's a lot to put in the code so I tought
I make a class with one parameter that reads out the section name but for one reason or the other this returns empty.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace base_ftp
{
    public class ConfigBuild
    {
        static AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();

        public void Now(string sectionname)
        {
            Console.Write(sectionname);
            
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            var configuration = builder.Build();
            ConfigurationBinder.Bind(configuration.GetSection(sectionname), appSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

In the appsettings.json I have something like

```json
"FtpSettings": {
     "FTP_SERVER": "xyz"
},
"Mailsettings": {
     "MAIL_SERVER": "xyz"
}
```

I call this in my main function like

```cs
string new_section = "FtpSettings";
ConfigBuild cnf = new ConfigBuild();
cnf.Now(sectionname:new_sectonname);
```

what am I overlooking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maybe misunderstood your question because I have not get the point in your last codeblock, but from what I get, I think this will help you:

```cs
    public class ConfigBuild
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ConfigBuild()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

            // create your 'IConfiguration' just once because you have already said it should 'reloadOnChange'
            _configuration = builder.Build();
        }
        
        public FtpSettings GetFtpSettings()
        {
            // Quick access method for your sections
            return GetSection<FtpSettings>(FtpSettings.SECTION_NAME);
        }
        
        public MailSettings GetMailSettings()
        {
            // Quick access method for your sections
            return GetSection<MailSettings>(MailSettings.SECTION_NAME);
        }
        
        public T GetSection<T>(string sectionName)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            // Access the sections in your 'IConfiguration' and bind them to a generic object. Generic because it can be used also for future sections.
            Console.WriteLine("SectionName: " + sectionName);
            return _configuration.GetSection(sectionName).Get<T>();
        }
    }
    
    // Model classes to bind your section to:

    public class FtpSettings 
    {
        public static readonly string SECTION_NAME = "FtpSettings";
        public string FTP_SERVER { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class MailSettings 
    {
        public static readonly string SECTION_NAME = "Mailsettings";
        public string MAIL_SERVER { get; set; }
    }
```

Here you can find a working example: [dotnet-fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p1wOVy)

[Documentation of configuration in net](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: thanks i have tested this out and with a few modifications this works now as expected thanks for the help.